# Selenium Webdriver length of xpath of an object

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I can find my object by xpath like `//div[@id='menu-groups-group1']`

this is -

```
//div[@id='menu']//div[@class='menu-items-block menu-groups']//div[@id='menu-groups-menu1']
```

the same object but longer xpath.

Does it matter what length of xpath of my object? Does it affects to the search speed of the object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it matters, and yes, it affects speed.

- `//div[@id='menu-groups-group1']` tells the XPath processor in WebDriver to find all the `<DIV>` elements in your document that have an `id` attribute of `menu-groups-group1`.  Then, depending on the operation you're performing (*e.g.*, `findElement()`, `findElements()`), it may or may not stop after locating the first one.
- `//div[@id='menu']//div[@class='menu-items-block menu-groups']//div[@id='menu-groups-menu1']` tells the XPath processor in WebDriver to find all the `<DIV>` elements in your document that have an `id` attribute of `menu`, then find all the `<DIV>` elements that are embedded at any depth within those elements and that have a `class` attribute of `menu-items-block menu-groups`, and then find all the `<DIV>` elements that are embedded at any depth within *those* elements and that have an `id` attribute of `menu-groups-group1'`.  Then, depending on the operation you're performing (*e.g.*, `findElement()`, `findElements()`), it may or may not stop after locating the first one.

As you can see, the longer XPath has much more complicated processing and creates potentially much larger sets of elements to examine.

You'd be much better off using the XPath `id('menu-groups-group1')`, or even using WebDriver's `By.id('menu-groups-group1')` instead.  The only reason to use the second form of your examples is if the `menu-groups-group1` id is not unique.  In which case, the developers should be very ashamed of themselves.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Which is faster by XPath id('menu-groups-group1') or WebDriver's By.id('menu-groups-group1')?